# How can I get codenameone client to work with a server supporting EventSource

Tags: codenameone

I am working with codenameone and trying to build a client to connect to a server that is using the Eventsource API to send real time updates. I have the javascript sdk but would rather use something more native to codenameone. IS there any such thing? Or does Codenameone ConnectionRequest support EventSource?

Answer (score 0):

At this time we don't have builtin support `EventSource` mostly because there is not that much demand for it. The only Java client side library for this I could find was this one: https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/eventsource-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/eventsource/client/impl/netty/EventSourceChannelHandler.java

Which is problematic as we don't support those specific API's (netty).

Most developers who need low level event based communications are using `WebSockets` which we support well through https://github.com/shannah/cn1-websockets/

You can also use direct TCP streams etc.

In a native app you would normally use push notification to trigger an update from the server. This works well for apps that aren't running. You can learn more about our push notification support [here](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-push-notification-send-server-push-messages.html).